# Codeception/PHPUnit Assert::isTrue pass with false

Tags: codeception

How come the following test pass, does this make sense?

```
<?php
use \Codeception\Util\Debug;
use \PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;

class TrackingCest
{
    // tests
    public function tryToTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        Debug::debug("I am really here!");
        Assert::isTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

enricog is right, you need to use

```
$I->assertTrue(false);
```

But you will need to enable the Asserts module in your configuration, in acceptance.suite.yml:

```
classname: AcceptanceTester
modules: 
    enabled:
        - Asserts
```

Besides that, there is no need to use the use statements at the top. 
Your test could look like this:

```
<?php

class TrackingCest
{
    // tests
    public function tryToTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        codecept_debug("I am really here!");
        $I->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not checking anything.

See implementation of PHPUnits `Assert::isTrue` method, it only returns a new `IsTrue` instance:

[PHPUnit::Assert](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/Assert.php)

To check for true with codeception you should use the methods on the injected **Tester**:

```
$I->assertTrue(false);
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont have that function available.

Comment: Yes, as @sunomad has meanwhile answered you also need to enable the ``Asserts`` module in your codeption/suite config then you can use those methods: https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Asserts